# Debugging on a remote server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I configured VSCode to debug the program via SSH on a remote server. In this case, VSCode looks for source code files on this server. How to tell him that the source code should be taken on another server (where the program was collected)?